# Compile-time Type Replacement in C++

Tags: c++, compilation

Say I have a program that uses a built in type such as `float` and I want to have the ability to supply a command-line argument to my compiler to change all `float` declarations to be `fixed_point<8,8>` instead.

Presuming that they're the exact same interface (as in, they can be treated the same with regards to assignment / addition / conversion / etc), is there a way in via compiler or build system (cmake / scons / etc) to swap types during compilation when specifying a specific flag? This would serve a few benefits with regards to determinism, for instance.

Comment: "is there a way in via compiler or build system (cmake / scons / etc) to ..." - A "build system" has no magic way for **compile** a file, it just runs a compiler passing this file and some other parameters as arguments. So, when ask whether a file could be compiled in some way, there is no reason to separate command-line compilation from compilation via "build tools".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare your variable with an alias type, which is defined conditionally based on a preprocessor definition, like this:

```
#ifdef LARGEFLOATS
using MYFLOAT = long double;
#else
using MYFLOAT = double;
#endif
```

You can then use the `-D` compiler flag to set the preprocessor definition, e.g. `-DLARGEFLOATS` (for MSVC, the syntax is `/D`). Need to be careful that all *translation units* see the same preprocessor definition. In my example, this could lead to a narrowing conversion.